# Text length reduction while storing in database table

Tags: mongodb, text, hash, compression, database

I am having a scenario in which the column of the table looks like as follows

1234124124124

2343243253253

2131324324324

4545645354356

0982349874598

1298349832595

5365240240324

0980979879832

0924320982438

....

So on many rows will be there. 
I want an efficient way to compress and store all these rows of that column in a single row. I just want to reduce the size occupied by the data with the concept of text compression or some similar functionality. while storing in same row even separators can also be used to store in the same row for differentiating them.

How can this be achieved?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to alter your schema to save disk space; MongoDB's WiredTiger storage engine includes [compression](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/wiredtiger/#compression), so you get the benefit of reduced disk space while keeping the schema you need to do your queries effectively.